# Component are repeated because of routing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have an issue where I use routing in component, which have childrens. In *RightMenuComponent* I have control which are duplicates. The children components like *EventListComponent* or *UserEventListComponent* shows only once according to path but when something is in parent (*RightMenuComponent*) it always duplicates.

Routing looks like below:
TS:

```
{
    path: '', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'events', component: RightMenuComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: EventListComponent },
      { path: 'mylist', component: UserEventListComponent }
    ]}]
},
```

HTML:

```
   <a [routerLink]="['/events']">Home</a>
   <a [routerLink]="['/events/mylist']">My List</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it might be finding two matches for the route "events" since they are the same so it's showing one rightmenucomponent alone and one rightmenu with eventlist. Maybe that helpa

Comment: i change it to diffrent path _EventListComponent_ was 'events/world' and _UserEventListComponent_ was 'events/mylist' and nothing has changed